# Is the limit of a periodic function its range?

Tags: calculus

Is it okay to say that the limit of a periodic function is the function's range? I figured that would be a safe way to express such a limit, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: If LhL and RHL are different how will the limit exist

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we are considering a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and taking the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$, then if $f$ is periodic this limit exists **only** if $f$ is constant.

Given what I assume is the level you are working at, the limit of a function can **never** be a range of values: It is either a particular point, or it fails to exist.

---

Answer (score 0):

The standard definition of a limit implies uniqueness, that is, as James states in his answer, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ of a periodic function $f$ exists only if $f$ is constant. However, every point of the range is an *accumulation point*, and there are a number of ways in which to state that. For instance: For every $y$ in the range of $f$ there exists a strictly increasing sequence of points $\{x_1, x_2, ...\}$ such that $y = \lim_{i\to\infty}f(x_i)$.